# Nutch not crawling page content

Tags: php, search, solr, nutch

I having a problem where I am unable to crawl content from a website which contains content from a php form. I am assuming that this is the problem as all other pages are being crawled without issues. I am using Nutch 1.11 and Apache Solr 5.4.1 to index the crawled documents into. The only text that gets index is the boilerplate text from the menu links etc. The whole body of text never gets parsed.

I am currently trying this with just the default configs except those that allow a php query to be executed in the URL so characters such as '?=' are accepted other than this its all default settings.
If anyone can thing of why this is the case I'd really appreciate it, I can't seem to find it as an issue anywhere online.

Below is an example site that I can't get the body text to be extracted and parsed.
https://www101.dcu.ie/prospective/deginfo.php?classname=BMED&originating_school=21

I've gone through the logs and it says it's parsed the url. Which it manages to extract the menu text but just none of the main content. And as I said all the other pages on the domain can be extracted without issues.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking query urls are ignored by default, this is because they can have a heavy hit on the crawled website (as a query url is normally dynamically generated from a datastore / db), in order to fix this, check the file where you put the regular expressions for your whitelists and there will be a comment in there explicitly saying the url pattern which is accepted - and this will need to be changed to allow for query urls (urls with ? in it).

file interested in is called: REGEX-URLFILTER.TXT

and will have:

`# regex-urlfilter.txt
+^http://www.example.com/browse
-[?]`

contents in

interesting blog on the matter: https://datafireball.com/2014/07/20/nutch-how-regex-urlfilter-txt-really-works/  - i am not affiliated